# unable to concat the output for multiple rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is like below

[image]

If i write a code like below

```
df.iloc[0]
```

[image]

And if i write code like below

```
df.iloc[3]
```

[image]

**I want to concat all the df.iloc[0], df.iloc[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq2uW.png), df.iloc[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzkfQ.png) untill whatever the max rows are are present. But with the help of for loop i'm unable to. Can anyone help me with this?**

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "until the max rows"? you mean until the last row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with comprehension:

```
df1 = pd.concat((df.loc[i] for i in df.index))
```

Or:

```
df1 = pd.concat((df.iloc[i] for i in range(len(df.index))))
```